# Connect to LiveLink and download document

Tags: c#, iso, livelink

I need to connect to LiveLink and download some ISO PDF files.

The way I connect is:

```
string url = "http://pod.iso.org/isostd/livelink?func=ll.login&Username=user&password=pasword";
string urlDoc = "http://pod.iso.org/isostd/livelink?func=doc.fetch&nodeid=705699&doctitle=ISO_11095";
string responseString = string.Empty;
WebRequest wReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)wReq;
httpReq.Method = "POST";
httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();            
string resp = response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

The variable resp gives me "OK", so I'm logged intoto the site but I don't know how to continue. The variable urlDoc is the url that of the document to download but I'm not able to continue.

Thnks in advance and excuse my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that works for me:

```
protected override void Login()
{
    var httpparams = new Hashtable();
    httpparams.Add("func", "ll.login");
    httpparams.Add("CurrentClientTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("D/yyyy/M/dd:H:m:s"));
    httpparams.Add("Username", this.LoginName);
    httpparams.Add("Password", this.Password);

    byte[] requestPostParams = WebHelper.GetWebPostData(httpparams);

    HttpWebRequest loginRequest = this.GetWebRequest(this.Uri);
    loginRequest.Method = "POST";
    loginRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(requestPostParams, 0, requestPostParams.Length);
    loginRequest.GetRequestStream().Close();

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)loginRequest.GetResponse();
    response.Cookies = loginRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(loginRequest.RequestUri);
}

public static byte[] GetWebPostData(Hashtable httpparams)
{
    StringBuilder requestStream = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (string paramname in httpparams.Keys)
    {
        if (requestStream.Length == 0)
        {
            requestStream.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}", paramname, httpparams[paramname]));
        }
        else
        {
            requestStream.Append(string.Format("&{0}={1}", paramname, httpparams[paramname]));
        }
    }
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(requestStream.ToString());
}
private void validateConnection()
{
    if ((!this._IsConnected) || this._LastExecutionTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15))
    {
        this._IsConnected = false;
        try
        {
            // recreate cookies container
            this._CookiesContainer = new CookieContainer();

            // login to livelink
            this.Login();

            this._IsConnected = true;
            this.ResetCounter();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string context = string.Format("Login to: {0}; user: {1}", this.Name, this.LoginName);
            this.NextAttempt(e, context);

            // try one more time
            this.validateConnection();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Download file from livelink based on provided query string
/// </summary>
public bool DownloadFileUri(string fileUri, string destinationFile)
{
    // validate input
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileUri))
        return false;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destinationFile))
        return false;

    // check that adapter is connected to livelink
    this.validateConnection();

    // get file content
    FileStream fs = null;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        //Retreive file
        var httpRequest = this.GetWebRequest(fileUri);
        httpRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpRequest.Proxy = ConnectorBase.GetProxy();
        response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

        int bytesRead;
        int bytesReceived = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[1000000];

        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        fs = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create);
        while ((bytesRead = receiveStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesReceived += bytesRead;
            this.OnDataDownload(bytesReceived);
        }

        // close file stream
        fs.Close();
        fs = null;

        // check file information
        var fi = new FileInfo(destinationFile);

        this.ResetCounter();

        // check file size and return true if file size > 0
        return fi.Length > 0;
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        ResetAdapter();

        string context = string.Format("Uri: {0}", fileUri);
        this.NextAttempt(e, context);

        return DownloadFileUri(fileUri, destinationFile);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ResetAdapter();

        string context = string.Format("Uri: {0}", fileUri);
        Logger.Error("Error: {0}, context: {1}", e.ToString(), context);

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
            fs.Close();
        if (response != null)
            response.Close();
    }
}
```

let me know if you need more help, in general, I can share code to download files or parse the content of the Livelink to download all documents referenced on the page

Answer (score 0):

In order to download document from Livelink, easy way would be to use LiveServices which are nothing but WCF Services of Livelink.
You can create an client and then by passing the ObjectId/DataId of the document you can download it. 
Let me know if you need help with the Client code..

Comment: Hi,Sorry for delaying my ansawer, but could not connect for two weeks. I'd appreciate some help with the client code, could you send me same samples? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Here's a simple method that will create a folder in Livelink. 

//LAPI Example

private int CreateFolder(int parentId, string folderName)
        {
llSession = new LLSession(host, Convert.ToInt32(port), string.Empty, userId, userPwd);
            int folderId = 0;
            LAPI_DOCUMENTS llDoc;
            LLValue objectInfo = (new LLValue()).setAssoc();

            try
            {
                llDoc = new LAPI_DOCUMENTS(llSession);
                if (llDoc.AccessEnterpriseWS(objectInfo) == 0)
                {
                    this.llDocuments = llDoc;
                    llDoc.CreateFolder(llVolume, parentId, folderName, objectInfo);
                    folderId = objectInfo.toInteger("ID");

                    log.Info(folderName + " folder created successfully");
                    return folderId;
                }
                else
                {
                    log.Info(folderName + " could not be created");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);
                return 0;
            }
        } 


//WCF Example getting Node info

 private void GetNodeInfo()
        {
            AuthenticationClient authClient = new AuthenticationClient();
            DocumentManagementClient docMan = new DocumentManagementClient();
            DocumentManagement.OTAuthentication otAuth = new DocumentManagement.OTAuthentication();
            string authToken = authClient.AuthenticateUser(userId, userPwd);
            otAuth.AuthenticationToken = authToken;

            try
            {
              DocumentManagement.Node node = new Node();

              node = docMan.GetNode(otAuth, Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[dataColumn].ToString()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                authClient.Close();
                docMan.Close();
            }
        }
```